# A fast way to sync local files with Proton Drive? (here exploring rclone)

Tags: synchronization, unison, synclient, rclone

I want to create a sync system between newly available Proton Drive and my local filesystem. However, since it's very new, it's only barely supported by `rclone` (I'm lucky to be on openSUSE Tumbleweed because rclone in my other distros don't support it), and it doesn't have a sync client for Linux yet.

I've considered 3 options:

1. mount the whole drive using `rclone mount` and work always online, but that's slow and sluggish and requires constant Internet connection;
2. mount drive with `rclone mount` and sync the folders I need using the tool [`unison`](https://github.com/bcpierce00/unison). But my testing shows that it can take a very long time for the software to browse for changes... Even though when the scanning is done it's pretty fast for the correct/copy;
3. use `rclone bisync`. But it's advertized to be in testing and not very stable, and anyways I have the same problem that I have with `unison`, it's very slow to browse for changes...

So if anyone has a better idea how to do that ("that" being setting up a sync system where when I change/add/remove something either on the computer or the drive, the change propagates to the other side immediately — or at least, fast, like, under a minute delay), please help!

```
rclone v1.64.2
- os/version: opensuse-tumbleweed (64 bit)
- os/kernel: 6.5.9-1-default (x86_64)
- os/type: linux
- os/arch: amd64
- go/versiorclone v1.64.2
- os/version: opensuse-tumbleweed (64 bit)
- os/kernel: 6.5.9-1-default (x86_64)
- os/type: linux
- os/arch: amd64
- go/version: go1.21.3
- go/linking: dynamic
- go/tags: none
n: go1.21.3
- go/linking: dynamic
- go/tags: none
```

That's the latest version of `rclone`.

I'm using Proton Drive's cloud storage solution.

`rclone config redacted` gives:

```
[proton]
type = protondrive
username = my.username
password = XXX
mailbox_password = XXX
client_uid = XXX
client_access_token = XXX
client_refresh_token = XXX
client_salted_key_pass = XXX
replace_existing_draft = true
### Double check the config for sensitive info before posting publicly
```

Comment: According to this (https://rclone.org/bisync/#supported-backends) `bisync` is not supported for `Proton Drive`. Also `rclone`'s `Proton Drive` backend is very buggy at the moment, even `copy/sync` doesn't work properly (https://github.com/rclone/rclone/issues/7322).

Comment: I don't even manage to `rclone mount` my ProtonDrive remote. I can `clone` and very slowly `sync`. For now to be honest I'm considering only manipulating tar with it, i.e not using it "properly" as I normally do with rsync.